# How show icon in BO with ZUL file

Tags: java, spring, sap-commerce-cloud, zul

I must show an icon (icon.png) on Backoffice. I have a controller class java where I choose where icon must appear (I have a folder "icons" and put a file "icon.png" into definition.xml). in zul file the tag is this :

```
<image src="icons/info.png" sclass="info-box-class" id="image"  />
```

Java class:

```
image.setTooltip("This is my tooltip");
        this.image.addEventListener(Events.ON_MOUSE_OVER, (event) -> {
            Popup p = new Popup();
            p.appendChild(new Label("Tooltip"));
            p.appendChild(new Label("Tooltip 2"));
```

Comment: where do you want to show the icon?

Comment: @RaushanKumar into reference search of an entity.

Comment: are you talking about list view search results?

Comment: @RaushanKumar I resolve the issues but I have only one problem..how change position of image? I want to put my image to the left of two others. How i do with zul file?